# Filter out non-user code methods from StackTrace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to implement somewhat more sophisticated error handling. To achieve my goal, I need to filter out non-user code methods (frames) from curent StackTrace.

In ASP.NET typical StackTrace as you can probably guess the are many methods that are quite irrelevant for debugging purposes as they are outside of the user code. Visual studio gives you option to filter out this non-user code (frames) so I am guessing its possible. However after about 30 minutes of exploring methods and properties of StackFrames (and methods, modules, assemblies, ... ) I couldnt find any that could be used to identify "system" frames.

I have ended up with manual specification of which modules I want to log (module is part of assembly, in my case 1:1).

Is there any better way to do this? Simply include everything outside core ASP.NET.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`StackFrame` class has the `GetMethod()` member function, from retrieved `MethodBase` object.

If all you need is a naive filter you may do one of these:

- Strip out every method in a class which starts with "System." or "Microsoft." (because all .NET libraries are placed there).
- Find the assembly where a method is (see forward) then check for `AssemblyCompanyAttribute` and filter assemblies made by "Microsoft Corporation"). This is better than previous method because sometimes I saw libraries which put their own types inside `System` namespace.

If you need something more you can get the module (`MethodBase.Module`) where that method is defined. Now you have two options:

- If all your assemblies are signed you can show only methods with that public key token (get the assembly where the module is defined with `Module.Assembly` property, build an `AssemblyName` object with `Assembly.FullName` then check the public key for `AssemblyName.KeyPair` property, it must match your public key token (simply compare with `GetExecutingAssembly()`).
- If not all your assemblies are signed you can do the same operation but filtering out all the assemblies that matches the public key token of *system* assemblies (this may be the simplest case and it'll include 3rd part libraries too).

Please note that not all system assemblies have the same public key token (even within the same Framework version) so you must collect and check a list of keys (just browse `c:\windows\assembly` to read them). A good approach could be to check for public key and then apply a second filter using `AssemblyCompanyAttribute`.

Comment: Thank you! I guess there is no direct way to do this (something like IsSystem property), albeit what you suggest is very close. Both naive and more sophisticated approaches seem quite logical. I am not very experienced with assembly signing but do system assemblies always have the same public key token regardless of their version?

Comment: No, not all assemblies (even within the same version) have the same public key token. You have to get the list (simply browse c:\windows\assembly) and filter them out. You may consider to use company name too (edited my answer).

Comment: In my solution, I made sure all my types were declared in my own namespace hierarchy. Since they all had the same root namespace, I just check the method's declaring type's full name `frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.FullName`.  If it matches `...FullName.StartsWith('MyRootNameSpace')`, it's my code, otherwise it's Microsoft's or some 3rd party's code.

Comment: Consider iterating through the stack trace from outer to inner frame, and only skipping frames outside your own code until you reach the first one inside your own code. It's common to call library code from within your own code, and you probably want to retain those parts of the stack trace.

Answer (score 7):

If you deploy your '*.pdb' files and you are only trying to get a stacktrace from an exception, you could take the exception's `StackTrace` property and split it into lines and filter out lines that don't have a source code reference.

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var lines = ex.StackTrace
                .Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Where(l => Regex.IsMatch(l, @"([^\)]*\)) in (.*):line (\d)*$"));
            var userStackTrace = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
        }
```

Comment: My +1, pretty good idea, even in production during debug phase when PDB are there.ù

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but I used NLog and TraceSource and redirected System.Net Trace Events to the NLog target. That said, filtering out System Assemblies didn't quite cut it, so I had to check the custom attributes:

```
    private static bool IsOkay(StackFrame arg)
    {
        var method = arg.GetMethod();
        var methodAttributes = new Attribute[] { }
            .Concat(method.GetCustomAttributes<DebuggerHiddenAttribute>())
            .Concat(method.GetCustomAttributes<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>());

        if (methodAttributes.Any())
            return false;

        var methodDeclearingType = method.DeclaringType;
        var methodDeclearingTypeAttributes = new Attribute[] { }
            .Concat(methodDeclearingType.GetCustomAttributes<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>());

        if (methodDeclearingTypeAttributes.Any())
            return false;

        var methodDeclearingTypeModule = methodDeclearingType.Module;
        var methodDeclearingTypeModuleAttributes = new Attribute[] { }
            .Concat(methodDeclearingTypeModule.GetCustomAttributes<UnverifiableCodeAttribute>());

        if (methodDeclearingTypeModuleAttributes.Any())
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

BR,
incureforce